# Problem of writing the "UTF-8" CSV file using PrintWriter

Tags: java, utf-8, printwriter

I have a problem of writing the UTF-8 character that cannot be properly read by Excel.   When I open the excel, some characters are read as "Ņӊഎ«". I understand this is something to do the UTF BOM. Is there someone who how can help to explain me this?

Here are my codes for writing the CSV.

public class FileWriter {
    private static String filenameTemp;

```
public static boolean creatFile(String name) throws IOException {
    boolean flag = false;
    filenameTemp = name + "";
    System.out.println("write to file: "+filenameTemp);
    File filename = new File(filenameTemp);
    if (!filename.exists()) {
        filename.createNewFile();
        flag = true;
    }
    else {
        filename.delete();
        filename.createNewFile();
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}

public static boolean writeFile(String newStr) throws IOException {
    boolean flag = false;
    String filein = newStr + "\r\n";
    String temp = "";

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(filenameTemp);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int j = 1; (temp = br.readLine()) != null; j++) {
            buf = buf.append(temp);
            buf = buf.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        buf.append(filein);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] unicode = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF};
        fos.write(unicode);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fos);


        pw.write(buf.toString().toCharArray());
        pw.flush();
        flag = true;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        throw e1;
    } finally {
        if (pw != null) {
            pw.close();
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if (isr != null) {
            isr.close();
        }
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: the method `toCharArray()` does not encode characters as UTF-8. I use `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`

Comment: can you be more specific for the code resvion?

Comment: Possible workaround: Use *Apache Commons CSV* to write your CSV. This tool supports flavors of CSV including MS Excel.